# How to get entity type from entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: entities

I can use

```
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', 1);
$entity->getBundle();
```

to get the node type of an entity. However, entity-wrappers can wrap other types of entities, e.g. users. When calling getBundle() on a user entity, 'user' is returned. What should I call to return the type of entity (should return 'node' in the example above)? I can see when I `print_r($entity)` that $entity->type is a protected field of the wrapper object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm, I seem to have found a way (unsure if this is the 'correct' way...)

```
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', 1);
$info = $entity->info();  // entity info as an array
$entity_type = $info['type']; // returns 'node' for node entities
```